# Can i have LINEFEED as separator in CONCAT_WS function of mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using a mySQL `CONCAT_WS()` function to get a set of comma separated values.

I need the output to appear as a set of rows instead of a **CSV**. How can this be done ?

Thanks,
Chak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS("\n", "row1", "row2", "row3");
> row1
  row2
  row3
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: you can also do stuff like this: CONCAT_WS(char(10 using utf8), "a","s","d") in case you need more control over the type of newlines used.

Comment: The current output with comma as separator is 
440fa6a7-a92e-4e8b-8198-d36004c14276, DEMOP, , 2010-08-02, , Haemogram,Blood Group

 I needed this to appear as

440fa6a7-a92e-4e8b-8198-d36004c14276, DEMOP, , 2010-08-02, , Haemogram
440fa6a7-a92e-4e8b-8198-d36004c14276, DEMOP, , 2010-08-02, , Blood Group

Comment: Please edit your question instead. Something ate your newlines. :)