# CONCAT_WS Separator

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation

i want to select a separator for CONCAT_WS() that not confilict by field value 
for example if i select "," maybe field value have string with ","
i want to select a seperator than not confilict by field value :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope U R USING PHP

choose your own separator like

```
$glue=®(alt 0174)


CONCAT_WS($glue,str1,$str2)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395419/can-i-have-linefeed-as-separator-in-concat-ws-function-of-mysql):

```
CONCAT_WS(char(22 using utf8), "this", "that");
```